# How to add border-top with rounded bottom corners to <li> elements?

Tags: html, css

I have menu

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}
li{  
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.selected{
  border-top:6px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="selected">Home</li>
     <li>Gallery</li>
     <li>About</li>
<ul/>
```

Need to add to selected

border-top 6px and the border must be with rounded bottom corners. Only border-top must appear, without moving

element.
Please help to solve this problem))

I attached small sketch to show what I need)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pseudo element:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}
li{  
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position:relative;
}
.selected:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:6px;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
     <li class="selected">Home</li>
     <li>Gallery</li>
     <li>About</li>
<ul/>
```